# Resolving FIPS Compliance Issues with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, fips-140-2

### Problem

I am working with Oracle DB 11g (11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit), Jenkins, Windows PowerShell plugin, and VsTestRunner plugin to automate running unit tests. While setting this up I stumbled upon a huge problem running `vstest.console.exe` in which I would get the following error: `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`. Through all my research, it has come to be proven to be caused by a FIPS compliance issue.

The only solution I have found that has proven to work is to alter the registry key associated with FIPS and disabling it (set 1 to 0). Unfortunately, this solution is not viable as the FIPS compliance is a requirement for the current environment.

A possible solution that was found was to update the Oracle DB to 12c Release 2 as it would resolve a known bug found in earlier releases; however, I have been told that this is not an option.

Of course, this has led me to here.

### Question

Does anyone know of any other possible solutions that would allow me to successfully connect to the Oracle database that would still be compliant with FIPS?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of another way.  My first task as a new admin was to upgrade to Oracle DB 12c Release 2 for the same issue.

Comment: @xguru : Thank you for the reply. I have been dealing with this for 2 days now and I'm at my wits end because I keep circling the same two answers...